# uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token < in calling JSP first line

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

when i am calling one jsp page from another jsp page using script tag the other jsp page is throwing error. and some unwanted tags are getting added to that page.

```
<script language="javascript"  src="<%= strDocRoot+"reports/reports/reporttree.jsp" %>"></script>
```

In my reporttree.jsp only javascript functions are there.

Comment: what does the first line of `reports/reports/reporttree.jsp` look like

Comment: is your src pointing to a jsp page or a javascript page?  You should not be trying to pull in a jsp with a script tag unless it is pure javascript

Comment: actually its working for ssl on tomcat and without ssl only with Apache server this problem is happening my report tree.jsp is as follows only javascript functions are there inside reporttree.jsp

Comment: https://mktfdh.aptean.com:8443/mk/wcs/reports/reports/reporttree.jsp   from this link you can access reporttree.jsp while accessing through application some html body and p tags are getting added

Comment: The link open a login page. Not a javascript

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you have still trouble, provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

JSP and JavaScript is not the same.

JSP, JavaServer Pages, is based on HTML, XML, or other document types. Therefore its could contain tags like `<tagname>`, but also JavaScript.

Javascript, dont use the same syntax. The `<` and `>` are mostry used to compare numbers.

In order to deliver an Javascript code from a JSP, you have to

- set the **content type to `application/javascript`**.
- And output only a valid javascript, without other tags.

Example:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8"%>

<%@ include file="yourJavascript.js"%>
```

The first three line will be processed by server to response headers.
The last one as response body.

Instead of the include directive you can use:

```
<jsp:include page="yourJavascript.js" />
```

Or just put the code of yourJavascript there:

```
alert("javascript loaded.");
```